# XSLT transforming flat xml with dot to hierarchical xml

Tags: xslt

I want to transform below XML using XSLT. This XML elements has dots to represent hierarchy

```
<UsrEmployee>
            <Code>70068579</Code>
            <Initials>F</Initials>
            <FirstName>Koichi</FirstName>
            <Prefix></Prefix>
            <LastName>Nakamura</LastName>
            <PropertyRef>70068579</PropertyRef>
            <SpaceRef.Code>001</SpaceRef.Code>
            <SpaceRef.FloorRef.Code>01</SpaceRef.FloorRef.Code>
            <SpaceRef.FloorRef.PropertyRef>70068579</SpaceRef.FloorRef.PropertyRef>
            <SpaceRef.propertyRef>70068579</SpaceRef.propertyRef>
        </UsrEmployee>
```

The above XML I want to transform as below XML, in the source XML element names can be any thing, number of dots(depth) is not known(not fixed). I want to create XSLT which would transform any generic XML of any size to hierarchical structure

```
<UsrEmployee>
    <Code>70068579</Code>
    <Initials>F</Initials>
    <FirstName>Koichi</FirstName>
    <Prefix></Prefix>
    <LastName>Nakamura</LastName>
    <SpaceRef>
        <Code>001</Code>
        <propertyRef>70068579</propertyRef>
        <FloorRef>
            <Code>01</Code>
            <PropertyRef>70068579</PropertyRef>
        </FloorRef>
    </SpaceRef>     
    <PropertyRef>70068579</PropertyRef>
</UsrEmployee>
```

Can someone help me on this

Comment: provide your XSLT

Comment: Do you know all the possible "dotted" elements in advance?  Do you know which elements may have dotted elements as children?

Comment: This is not really a Java question.  The question and answers would be the same for any language or XSLT tool.

Comment: edited my original post

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'll edit my question. I have no control on the depth of dotter elements and also the node names. It can by any node name. I am looking for something generic.

Comment: What you're asking -- interpreting element names non-atomically -- is unnatural for XSLT.  I'm not quite prepared to say that it cannot be done, but you should consider implementing a custom function or performing part or all of the desired transformation via a programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Just create matching templates for your "dotted" elements and apply them.

Use `select` to control the "catch-all" identity template (the last template in the xslt)

Of course this may be an oversimplified solution and a more complex transformation will be needed if you have an arbitrary hierarchical structure where selecting your templates like this is not practicable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="UsrEmployee">
        <xsl:element name="UsrEmployee">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Code | Initials | FirstName | Prefix | LastName | PropertyRef" />

            <xsl:element name="SpaceRef">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="SpaceRef.Code | SpaceRef.propertyRef" />

                <xsl:element name="FloorRef">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="SpaceRef.FloorRef.Code | SpaceRef.FloorRef.PropertyRef" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SpaceRef.Code">
        <xsl:element name="Code">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SpaceRef.propertyRef">
        <xsl:element name="propertyRef">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SpaceRef.FloorRef.Code">
        <xsl:element name="Code">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SpaceRef.FloorRef.PropertyRef">
        <xsl:element name="PropertyRef">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That should work for given input. I did not specified earlier. but I am looking for something generic. Question is edited.